# How to extract every 7 characters of an nvarchar into another table?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, ssis, etl

I have an nvarchar(200) called ColumnA in Table1 that contains, for example, the value:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

I want to extract every 7 characters into Table2, ColumnB and end up with all of these values below.

```
ABCDEFG
BCDEFGH
CDEFGHI
DEFGHIJ
EFGHIJK
FGHIJKL
GHIJKLM
HIJKLMN
IJKLMNO
JKLMNOP
KLMNOPQ
LMNOPQR
MNOPQRS
NOPQRST
OPQRSTU
PQRSTUV
QRSTUVW
RSTUVWX
STUVWXY
TUVWXYZ
```

*[Not the real table and column names.]*

The data is being loaded to Table1 and Table2 in an SSIS Package, and I'm puzzling whether it is better to do the string handling in TSQL in a SQL Task or parse out the string in a VB Script Component.

*[Yes, I think we're the last four on the planet using VB in Script Components. I cannot persuade the other three that this C# thing is here to stay.  Although, maybe it is a perfect time to go rogue.]*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE calculating the offsets step by step and `substring()`.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT 1 n
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 n
       FROM cte
       WHERE n + 1 <= len('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') - 7 + 1
)
SELECT substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', n, 7)
       FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6779f09d5fd391086c92ab4aaf48fc70)

Comment: I like this approach, but whenever you use a recursive CTE to create a *tally-on-the-fly*, you must be aware of the max depth of 100 which might need an `OPTION MAXRECURSION` on the outermost query whenever you use this... That's why I perefer a numbers table or a solution via `ROW_NUMBER` against any larger set (which you can CROSS JOIN) to any needed number. I placed an answer myself.... +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a physical numbers table, this is easy. If not, you can create a *tally-on-the-fly*:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

--We create the tally using `ROW_NUMBER` against any table with enough rows.

```
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(SELECT TOP(LEN(@string)-6) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT Nmbr
      ,SUBSTRING(@string,Nmbr,7) AS FragmentOf7
FROM Tally
ORDER BY Nmbr;
```

The idea in short:
The tally returns a list of numbers from 1 to n (n=LEN(@string)-6). This Number is used in `SUBSTRING` to define the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with T-SQL like this:

```
DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT [ColumnA] FROM [Table1]
OPEN C

DECLARE @Val nvarchar(200);
FETCH NEXT FROM C into @Val
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INTEGER;
    SELECT @I = 1;
    WHILE @I <= LEN(@vAL)-6 BEGIN
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@Val, @I, 7)
        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM C into @Val
END
CLOSE C
```

Comment: `CURSOR` was introduced by the devil of procedural thinking  to lead us poor  little database people into the dark and evil. Come into the light of *set-based-thinking* and avoid `CURSOR`, `WHILE` and *multi-statement-functions* whenever you can. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Script Component solution

*Assuming that the input Column name is `Column1`*

1. Add a script component
2. Open the script component configuration form
3. Go to Inputs and Outputs Tab
4. Click on the Output icon and set the `Synchronous Input` property to `None`
5. Add an Output column *(example `outColumn1`)*
6. In the Script editor, use a similar code in the row processing function:

```vb
Dim idx as integer = 0

While Row.Column1.length > idx + 7

    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
    Output0Buffer.outColumn1 = Row. 
    Column1.Substring(idx,7)

    idx +=1

End While
```